# How do I produce a peristimulus time-histogram for a discrete event relative to another event in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a numpy array of timestamps(ms) for two events. I would like to define a function which will take one array as a reference event, and the other as data, compute a sparse matrix of dimensions 0:len(reference event) x a defined window of time around each reference event, and plot the result as a peristimulus time-histogram.

I think the first step is to append the data array to the end of the ref array and use the argsort function to arrange the indices:

```
x = np.array(ref_event)
y = np.array(data_event)
cat = np.append(x,y)
ind = np.argsort(cat)
```

but after this I have no idea what to do.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are vectors of corresponding time points can't you just take the difference and make a histogram?